# web2py db manual table entries

Tags: web2py

So, in my db.py, I defined a table as such:

```
db.define_table('dummy',
            Field('name'),
            Field('category'),
            Field('number'))
```

But how would I add my own values in that table? It seems like if I do something like:

```
db.dummy.insert(name='jon',category='cat',number='2')
```

I get a "Database is locked" error. So, how can I have my own manual table? I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you just haven't committed a previous database insertion (are you using the interactive shell?). Try adding a

```
db.commit()
```

after the database insertion code. You might also have to do it once before to commit the current change that is keeping the database locked.